# c# variables with unit testing

Tags: c#, mstest

I am new to unit testing, so I am trying out a few basic programs to test it with. If I        have created a class with a private variable and declared two functions, is there a way that the second function can access the updated variable's value? In the example below when I call the temp function in my unit test, after the add function, it returns 0 (the initial value), not the updated value of whatever was added to Storage. Is there a way I can return the updated value here?

```
// Class scope variable
Private int storage = 0;

Public int Storage
{
   get { return storage; }
   set { storage = value; }
}
Public void add(int pass)
{
   Storage += pass;
}

Public int temp (){
   return Storage;
}
```

```
// Testing 
namespace TestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void Adding_Storage()
        {
            Class1 class1 = new Class1();

            class1.add(5);
            int result = testing.temp();
            Assert.AreEqual(5, result);  

        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Display_Storage()
        {
            Class1 class1 = new Class1();

            class1.temp();
            int result = class1.temp();
            Assert.AreEqual(0, result);
  
            // this is where I would like result to return 5,
            // but it still returns 0.
        }
```

Comment: Yes, but its a bit different depending on your unit testing framework, please include your test case and tag with the framework you are using. I think I know what you mean, but we need this clarity to involve the wider community in the discussion

Comment: Included. This is the .Net framework 4.7.2

Comment: In the second test you create a new `Class1` and never call `add()` so that's why the value is zero.

Comment: Unclear why you're using the `temp()` method rather than just testing the value of `Storage`?

Comment: Please post real code. You have capitals in keywords.

Comment: you can use `[ClassInitialize]` and some static members to setup state that each test can assert against; but when doing this, you should not write tests that would then be order-dependent. you should instead setup your test specifically for each test. if you have repeat setup code, push it to a non-test method that creates the same setup for many tests. but only do that if there is a lot of benefit to doing so.

Comment: When you have an issue like, "this is where I would like result to return 5, but it still returns 0," then you have one of two situations. Either your code is  wrong or your test is wrong. In this case, your test is wrong. Returning `0` is correct or you need to add the `class1.add(5);` line in to your test.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are creating a *new* instance of the test target class in each test.

Ideally, for each test case, you should setup the pre-conditions first, you should avoid using the output of previous tests in your current test case. So it is possible that using the `[TestInitialize]` will provide a solution for you, it is not a good idea to do so. Its an anti-pattern.

In the display storage, you should setup a known state before you test:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Display_Storage()
    {
        // setup the pre-conditions for this specific test case
        Class1 class1 = new Class1();
        int expectedResult = 5;
        class1.add(expectedResult);

        // this is the behaviour this method is testing
        int result = class1.temp();
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, result);
    }
```

---

You can setup a common `Class1` instance that is shared across the tests, but this very quickly leads to issues and leaky tests... [Read more about `\[TestInitialize\]` here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/test-initialize-and-test-setup/), but reserve this for initialization of static or immutable resources.

If your test relies on the outcome of other tests, then the order of execution of the tests becomes paramount to the test actually passing or not. This actually makes testing and reviewing test cases much harder.

The point of testing is to verify functionality. You can have a test that verifies that the object retains state, then in other tests we *assume* that the state retention can be trusted (that is a dependant test case) and focus on testing just the behaviour of that test case.

To explain, look at your first test, it verifies that `add(int)` works. Now other tests we do not need to verify the outcome of `add(int)` to the same degree that we would in the first test. We can simply use the method.

- Your first test really should cover boundary conditions and known failure points, at the very least it should test passing through `Int32.MaxValue` and `Int32.MinValue`. but this is not a code review...

If the first test fails, then the second test is also going to fail, but this is expected, but now if you run just the second test independently it can pass without forcing the tester to also test the first case, first.

We don't need to validate that `.add()` specifically works in the second test, but we should use those dependant method calls to help catch issues in cases when testers do only test individual test cases.

Comment: I like this answer, but I disagree that `[TestInitialize]` is an anti-pattern for this situation. It might not be the solution requiring the least amount of code, but it would work and be easy enough to maintain. What I really like about your answer is simply adding a second assert. Too frequently we forget that we are testing behaviors and requirements. Multiple asserts are just fine in one unit test, as long as they are cohesive. I think they are cohesive in the OP's case.

Comment: You need to be careful with `[TestInitialize]`  because it is easy to fall into the trap of creating sequentially dependent test cases. `new Class1()` is all you would be putting in your init logic in this case, so we don't gain anything by using `[TestInitialize]`

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way that the second [test] can access the updated variable's value?

Yes, you could instantiate `Class1` at `UnitTest1`'s scope, rather than instantiating a local variable. However, you probably **don't want** to do this.

There are three approaches to designing tests:

- Declare all variables as local: The advantage of this is that they're all cleaned up at the end of the tests.
- Declare some variables at class scope. Ensure that their values are reset between tests using the MSTest `setUp` and `tearDown` methods. Each individual test should not affect subsequent tests. The order in which tests are run should not affect whether they pass.
- Share variables between tests such that each test-case method is actually part of a longer test. The order in which tests are run affects whether tests pass and you need a deep understanding of your own code to diagnose why a test has failed. Some people take this approach for long tests (more than 10 minutes) but it's rarely desirable.

If you are just starting out, you should prefer the first approach. As you become more familiar, you can try the second approach. You don't need to try the third approach.

If you do need to initialise variables a similar way for multiple tests, you can always create a shared method that does the initialisation before you do the testing.